# Error handling while using chain of groups in celery

Tags: django, celery, celery-task, celerybeat, djcelery

I have 100 tasks. But I want to process only 4 tasks at a time. Once these 4 tasks get completed i want to run the next set of 4 tasks. 
This can be done by grouping tasks in sets of 4 and then chaining them.
But some tasks may fail in between, how can I handle these errors and take appropriate actions, so that I retry for only the tasks that failed. 
As per my knowledge in a chain if one task fails, the subsequent tasks in the chain will not run. So if I implement chain of groups, if any tasks in a group fails, the entire chain will fail. 
Suggest me a proper error handling method for this, also any better idea for implementing this will be appreciated.

I have disabled the result backend.

A little background - I have a cron running every 30s implemented using celery-beat which picks up 100 new tasks at a time. So all these chaining and grouping has to be done inside the cron function.

I am using celery 3.1.25

Comment: Do the next set of tasks require the first set of tasks to be run?

Comment: @schillingt no it's not required. All tasks are independent of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Don't chain the tasks together if they are independent. [Adjust the settings](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) on the celery worker for a specific queue to limit the number of workers to 4 using `--concurrency 4` or `-c 4`.

Comment: you mean that I feed all the 100 tasks to the queue, but since no of worker is 4 only 4 tasks will be processed at a time

Comment: Basically, yes. You might have to tune some other settings, but that is the approach I would take.

Comment: Right now i'm running only 1 worker with concurrency of 4, I think this configuration alone can help me in achieving what i want. I just need to feel all of them at once to the queue.